# codeigniter shopping cart and multiple tables

Tags: mysql, database, codeigniter, shopping-cart

I'm pretty new to codeigniter and I am trying to get to know databases better so I decided to follow [this guide](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/how-to-build-a-shopping-cart-using-codeigniter-and-jquery/).

However I want to go a bit more advanced and try it over multiple pages with multiple tables, I have sort of got it half working but when I click add to cart it always selects the item from database 1. It uses

```
$this->db->where('id', $id);  
$query = $this->db->get('fruit', 1);
```

to add the item to the cart. But I want it to be able to select from more than one table eg.  fruit and veg  where they would both be in a different table but have the same columns, is there anyway to easily do this using joins or any other method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, have you look into [codeigniter active record](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/active_record.html#select)?

```
Something like?
$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->from('fruit');
$this->db->join('veg', 'fruit.id = veg.id');

$query = $this->db->get();

// Produces:
// SELECT * FROM fruit
// JOIN veg ON veg.id = fruit.id
```

Edit:
   From your description in your comment, I constructed these two tables.

```
   mysql> desc fruit;
   +-------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
   | Field | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
   +-------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
   | id    | int(11)     | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
   | name  | varchar(29) | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
   | price | int(11)     | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
   +-------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
   3 rows in set (0.00 sec)

   mysql> desc veg;
   +-------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
   | Field | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
   +-------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
   | id    | int(11)     | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
   | name  | varchar(20) | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
   | price | int(11)     | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
   +-------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
   3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

This is an example of the function test using multiple and joins. I think this is your final sql query?

```
SELECT *
FROM (`fruit`)
JOIN `veg` ON `fruit`.`id` = `veg`.`id` and fruit.name = veg.name and fruit.price = veg.price
WHERE `fruit`.`id` =  1
```

And this is the corresponding codeigniter query.

```
public function testJoins() {
    $id = 1;
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('fruit');
    $this->db->join('veg', 'fruit.id = veg.id and fruit.name = veg.name and fruit.price = veg.price');
    $this->db->where('fruit.id', $id);

    $query = $this->db->get();
    return $query->result();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for replying. I have tried this but every ID now has the same name and price as the item on veg and when I join more tables using `'fruit.id = veg.id AND fruit.name = veg.name AND fruit.price = veg.price'` it gives product doesn't exist. Again thanks for replying.

Comment: tell me what is your final sql query, i will construct the query using ci active record syntax.

Comment: `$id = $this->input->post('product_id');  
$qty = $this->input->post('quantity');  
$this->db->select('*');  
$this->db->from('fruit');  
$this->db->join('veg', 'fruit.id = veg.id AND fruit.name = veg.name AND fruit.price = veg.price');  
$query = $this->db->get();  ` Would removing the line  `$this->db->where('id', $id); // Select where id matches the posted id`  Have anything to do with it?